# How to make multiple UILabels to self resize in a UITableView Cell?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, uilabel

I have a `TableViewController` Swift project in Xcode.
I made 3 labels: a `titleLabel`, a `deadlineLabel` and a `noteLabel`.

How to make the `titleLabel` and `deadlineLabel` to self resize and change their position in cell when `noteLabel` is empty?

Or how to make the `titleLabel` to self resize and change its position when both `deadLineLabel` and `noteLabel` don't appear?

Thank you in advance!

Below are some of my codes:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   // let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("todoCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) // retrieve the prototype cell (subtitle style)

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("todoCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ToDoTableViewCell


    let todoItem = todoItems[indexPath.row] as ToDoItem

    cell.titleLabel.text = todoItem.title as String!

    if (todoItem.isOverdue) { // the current time is later than the to-do item's deadline
        cell.deadlineLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
    } else {
        cell.deadlineLabel.textColor = UIColor.blueColor() // we need to reset this because a cell with red subtitle may be returned by dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:indexPath:
    }

    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "'Due' MMM dd 'at' h:mm a" // example: "Due Jan 01 at 12:00 PM"
    cell.deadlineLabel.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(todoItem.deadline)

    cell.noteLabel.text = todoItem.note as String!
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that.

Or to be academic about it: You can have the cell view automatically rezised upon the size of its content but that alone does not help you much.

You will have to respond accordingly to calls of `tableView(_:heightForRowAtIndexPath:)` .
So overwrite this method of the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol an do the size calculation there and return its height accordingly.